# L90 bootloop - no emergency mode, no download mode, pc doesn't recognize

Tags: boot-loop, unbricking, lg-optimus-l90

Good afternoon,

I'm facing a problem on my colleague's LG L90 phone, it suddenly started to bootloop and nothing seems to solve the problem.

The only way to turn it off is to remove the battery, but as soon as you put it back (be it instantly after removing it or after any period of time) the phone turns on and starts to bootloop again, so there's no "turn it off and turn on again pressing x buttons". The bootloop lasts about 10 seconds before it restarts the process.

When I connect it to my PC with the battery nothing changes, and the PC doesn't recognize the device, as it reboots before the PC can see it. Plugging it without the battery shows a screen with an empty battery for some seconds and then it reboots, showing that screen again.

I tried to enter recovery mode, emergency mode and fastboot mode without success. Plugging the phone on the PC or placing the battery while pressing vol -, vol +, both or any with the power button simply has no effect on the phone, it just keeps bootlooping.

The phone model is LG-D410hn, and it doesn't have unlocked bootloader, root or anything similar, it has everything stock.

Does anyone know what I can do to try to save it?

Comment: Is it being recognized by the PC in ADB? Connect it with PC & try the "adb devices" command.. If ADB can detect it you can boot into fastboot mode through it..

Comment: No, the PC doesn't recognize it, adb devices return nothing, and the device keeps restarting.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same device and experienced the same behavior and it turned out to be my SD card. After I removed it my phone worked fine. I never did find out what the problem with the SD card was. I inserted it into an adapter and put it in my chromebook to see if I could run some diagnostics tool on it but it even caused my chromebook to reboot!
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're still stuck, I recommend flashing the stock firmware using a flash tool. You can find a lot of tutorials online about it. Just do a quick Google search for "LG L90 stock firmware" and you'll find some good tutorials. This method might cause data loss if you download the whole firmware by reformatting the device. So be careful about that.

Here's a quick link to a website which might help
For LG Optimus L90 D405N, go here:
https://lgstockrom.com/lg-optimus-l90-d405n

For LG L90 Dual D410HN, go here:
https://lgstockrom.com/lg-l90-dual-d410hn

I hope that it helps